# Avoid check if logger exists

Tags: python, logging, nonetype

When using logging in python like this

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = None
if <some condition>:
   logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
... some code ...
logger.debug('message')
```

is it possible to avoid calling `logger.debug` if it does not exist without `if` statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could construct a wrapper object and use that everywhere:

```
class LoggerWrapper(object):

    def __init__(self, logger):
        self.logger = logger

    def debug(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.logger is None:
            return
        self.logger.debug(*args, **kwargs)

my_wrapper = LoggerWrapper(logger)
my_wrapper.debug('message')
```

That being said, this is not specific to Python's logging module. Any variable `var` that can also be `None` will need to be checked before you call a method on it (`var.method()`).

It may be easier to always define a logger and to simply disable the logging through the logging configuration / settings. That keeps the code clean, all logger calls will succeed but the output won't go anywhere if that particular logger is disabled.

Lastly, you could opt to indeed use an if statement as it's not inherently that much more code:

```
if logger:
    logger.debug('message')
```

Answer (score 7):

That's not how you use logging: it's missing the point entirely. The point is to always just log, and then (at the app level) configure handlers appropriately so that they either record the debug level or not. Your app-level configuration can even set the handler for loggers in each module. See the Python logging docs for more info.

Comment: You are right, but sometimes you could want to use logging not in a app, so  there is no app level. For instance, use logging in stand alone services. In this case, loggers may be duplicated, and this is not wanted

Comment: This approach is not helpful, for instance, if you are developing a library that should not include its own logging config. Consumer apps or clients will install the library, and its logging statements will automatically work with the client's chosen log configuration. But then what do you do for local development of the library itself? You may want to execute a section of code that should not define any log handler, but still see output from e.g. `log.warn`. It would be nice if Python cleanly defaulted to a base logger for this.

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to avoid calling logger.debug if it does not exist without if statement?

Well, you could (ab)use an `if` expression, or an `or` expression, or various other things, but otherwise, not really.

You can, however, always write a wrapper function:

```
def logdebug(*args):
    if logger:
        logger.debug(*args)

logdebug('message')
logdebug('other message')
```

---

You can do other, similar tricks. For example, instead of having `logger = None`, you can create an object that has a `debug` method that does nothing:

```
class Dummy(object):
    def debug(self, *args): pass
logger = Dummy()
```

---

Or, even better, always create a logger and configure it with a null handler, or—simplest of all—just set its logging level higher than debug.

---

But note that none of these will *completely* replace the `if` statement. Consider, for example:

```
if logger:
    logger.debug(very_expensive_function())

logdebug(very_expensive_function())
```

The first one will only call `very_expensive_function` to create the log message if you actually need it; the second one will always call it and then just throw it away if you don't need it.